# How to clone repositiry from git into windows different folders

Tags: github

Is it possible to clone the git repository into different folder through git interface, because under one git repository we maintain different branches. Initially clone one branch to my local, now i want clone the same folder into different folder. While i am trying to clone it shows this repository is already existed. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer depends on what you mean by "through the git interface"

If you mean via the git command line interface, the answer is to simply add the path to where you want to clone the repo as an argument to the command , i.e.

```
git clone -b yourdifferentbranch https://github/youruser/yourrepo yourdifferentdir
```

If by git interface you mean the GitHub for Windows  client, when you start the client, go to the Settings gear in the upper right corner , Select Options, and then change the "Clone path" directory .  I assume the github for mac client is the same but I don't have a mac.

If you mean some other git interface I apologize for leaving it out of the answer